# Solve $x^k \exp(-x)=a$ for $x$ and some inequalities

Tags: calculus, inequality, lambert-w

I am trying to characterize the set i
\begin{align}
A_{a,k}=\{ x \ge 0:  x^k \exp(-x) > a \}
\end{align}
in terms of inequaliti on $x$ where $a$ and $k$ are some give positive numbers.  That is I am trying to find
\begin{align}
A_{a,k}=\{ x \ge 0:   g_1(a) \le x \le g_2(a) \}.
\end{align}

The function   $x^k \exp(-x)$ has maximum  at $x=\sqrt{k}$. So, we have to assume that $a \le  k^{k/2}e^{-k}$ for the set to be non-empty.

To characterize $g_1$ and $g_2$ we would need to solve 
\begin{align}
x^k \exp(-x) = a
\end{align} 
This should have to solution if $a$ is strictly less than  $k^{k/2}e^{-k}$.   However, I cannot find these.

WolframAlpha gives me a solution in terms of $W$ function
\begin{align}
x=  -k W \left(-\frac{a^{1/k}}{k} \right)
\end{align}

However, it doesn't give me the second solution.

Finally my question is:   What are $g_1$ and $g_2$. ?

I think 
\begin{align}
g_1 =  -k W_0 \left(-\frac{a^{1/k}}{k} \right)
\end{align}
where  $W_0 $ is the zero branch

Comment: A general advice : plot function $f_k(x)=x^k e^{-x}$ : things will appear in a clearer light.

Comment: @JeanMarie  i have. I has a bump at $x=\sqrt{k}$ and line $y=a$ crosse it twice. That is why I am asking for two function $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$.  I am I wrong here?

Comment: @g.kov  Thank you.  Can you put this as an answer? I want to give you credit and maybe ask to clarify some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression
\begin{align} 
x&=  -k \operatorname{W} \left(-\frac{a^{1/k}}{k} \right)
\end{align}

means two real solutions,

\begin{align} 
x_{0}&=  -k \operatorname{W_0} \left(-\frac{a^{1/k}}{k} \right)
,\\
x_{-1}&=  -k \operatorname{W_{-1}} \left(-\frac{a^{1/k}}{k} \right)
\\
\text{for }\quad 
-\tfrac1k{a^{1/k}}\in(-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}},0)
,
\end{align}

where $\operatorname{W_0},\operatorname{W_{-1}}$
are so-called two real branches of the Lambert W function.

In this case $x_0<x_{-1}$, since 
for the argument $z:\ -\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}}<z<0$,

\begin{align}
\operatorname{W_{-1}(z)}&<-1<\operatorname{W_{0}(z)}<0
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The Lambert W function has branches.  The (complex)  solutions of $x^k e^{-x} = a$ are $x = -k W_i(-a^{1/k}/k)$ where $W_i$ is any branch of the Lambert W function, and $a^{1/k}$ is any branch of the $k$'th root of $a$. The principal ($0$) branch of $W$ gives you a real solution if $-a^{1/k}/k \ge -e^{-1}$, while the $-1$ branch gives you a real solution if $-e^{-1} \le -a^{1/k}/k < 0$.

Comment: Can you give more details on how I just connect $g_1$ and $g_2$ to $W$ function?  I